# Order parameters in Swagger with Python flask-restplus/x

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I'm documenting my REST endpoints with Flask-restx (Python 2.7) and the parameters to the endpoints get really strange sorting in Swagger. Right now the required parameters are not always first in the list.

[Output in Swagger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBk3.png)

It seems to be a way to sort the parameters in some way with "sortParamsByRequiredFlag", but I don't see where I can set it. Anyone knows?

My code for one of the endpoints:

```py
@g_api.route('/apx_export', methods=['GET'])
@g_api.doc(params={
    'date_time_start': {
        'required': True,
        'type': 'string',
        'format': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'description': 'Start date'},
    'date_time_end': {
        'required': False,
        'type': 'string',
        'format': 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        'description': 'End date'},
    'portfolio': {
        'required': False,
        'type': 'string',
        'description': 'The apx id of the account or portfolio to be filtered on'}, })
class ApxExport(Resource):
    def get(self):
        date_time_start = _unicode_to_latin1(flask.request.args.get(key='date_time_start', default=None, type=str))
        date_time_end = _unicode_to_latin1(flask.request.args.get('date_time_end', None))
        apx_portfolio = _unicode_to_latin1(flask.request.args.get('portfolio', None))

        if date_time_start is None:
            def apx_error_binder():
                raise ServerError('apx_export: date_time_start is unassigned', status_code=400, include_traceback=False)

            return QueuedCall.redirect(apx_error_binder)

        def apx_export_binder():
            return ipm.ats.apx_export.apx_export(date_time_start, date_time_end, apx_portfolio)

        return QueuedCall.redirect(apx_export_binder)
```

The output in Swagger is in this order:

**date_time_end**, string($YYYY-MM-DD), (query), End date

**portfolio**, string, (query), The apx id of the account or portfolio to be filtered on

**date_time_start** *, string($YYYY-MM-DD), (query),Start date

Comment: Please include your code, the current output, and a mockup of the desired output. This will help us to answer your question.

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks, I added some code and output.

Comment: I tried with collections.OrderedDict, but as excepted it had no effect.